# How can I extract only plain text from the column values in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, substring, calculated-columns, alphanumeric

I have a column (Existing Col) containing alphanumeric values from which I have to extract only plain text as shown in the example below:

| Existing Col | Required Col |
| --- | --- |
| G14 - Chocolate money 543 | Chocolate money |
| Parking amount Q89 | Parking amount |
| 19 - Chips fee - 20 | Chips fee |
| 698 Ticket fee | Ticket fee |

I tried the SUBSTRING function but not able to modify it to take just plain text and ignore everything else.

`SUBSTRING ( Existing Col,5 ,10 )`

Comment: Probably regexp_replace something

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you always have at least two words, you can use:

```
select regexp_substr(val, '([A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z ]+[A-Za-z]+)( |$)')
from (select 'G14 - Chocolate money 543' as val union all
      select 'Parking amount Q89' union all
      select '19 - Chips fee - 20' union all
      select '698 Ticket fee'
     ) x
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0a17a41ed4cf41f5d8bca6f3353319c7) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you for the response, it works fine as shown in db<>fiddle, but how can I pass the column name instead of passing individual values?

Comment: @PreethamCS . . . You just pass the column name as in the example (where the column is called `val`).

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear when I said column name, I'm looking for a way to just pass the column "Existing Col" to the query instead of individual select statements for the values, as there are more than 100 records in the column.

Comment: @PreethamCS. . . `regexp_substr(existing_col, '([A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z ]+[A-Za-z]+)( |$)')`.